How can I filter data using Evrete Rule Engine
I want to use rule engine to filter out data.
For e.g. if there are 10 Account records, I would like to apply a rule like all accounts which are less than 1 year old.
I am exploring Evrete Rule engine but didn't find any way where I can pass list of the 10 accounts and it'll return the subset of accounts matching the criteria.
With the rules I have configured it applies the rule to the matched accounts but doesn't reduce the account list.
